# Dificuldade com responsivo

Tags: html, css

Estou criando um site para testes, o menu dele está responsivo, a parte do texto não estou conseguindo deixar responsivo, sabe o que estou fazendo de errado?

https://jsfiddle.net/abudc84k/

Obs¹: Ignorem o texto do site, foi só pra testar mesmo.
Obs²: a tag meta está assim, como sugerido por outro site

Answer (score 1):

É porque simplesmente não tem regra nenhuma pra suas colunas dentro do media-query (`@media screen and (max-width: 600px)`), ou seja se você não "programou" para fazer a "ação" como espera que ela funcione? Então basta ajustar o código usando os media-query (`@media screen and (max-width: 600px)`).

Outro detalhe, dentro de `<head></head>` adicione isto (pode ajustar):

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
```

E se estiver usando IE-8, 9 e 10 com o DOCTYPE para HTML5 adicione esta meta-tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

O código deve ficar assim:

> **Notas:**
>
> Removi o `body { margin: 0; }` porque isso já existia no outro seletor e removi seletores não usados
>
> Movi o media-query pro final pra manter a ordem da "cascata"

```css
body{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
}


/* CONFIGURAÇÃO MENU */

ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 1.5% 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #d10000;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-size: 16pt;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #3d3d3d; border: 1px solid white;}

ul.topnav li a.active {background-color: #3d3d3d; border: 1px solid white;}

ul.topnav li.right {float: right; border: 1px solid white;}


/* CONFIGURAÇÃO CONTEUDO DIREITA */
.a-right {
 padding: 2%;
 float: right;
 width: 30%;
}

.a-center {
 padding: 2%;
 width: 60%;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    ul.topnav li.right, 
    ul.topnav li {float: none;}
   .a-center, .a-right {
       width: auto;
       float: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Novidades</a></li>
  <li class="right"><a href="#about">Sobre</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="a-right">
 <p>Podemos acreditar que tudo que a vida nos oferecerá no futuro é repetir o que fizemos ontem e hoje. Mas, se prestarmos atenção, vamos nos dar conta de que nenhum dia é igual a outro. Cada manhã traz uma benção escondida; uma benção que só serve para esse dia e que não se pode guardar nem desaproveitar.</p>
 
 <p>Se não usamos este milagre hoje, ele vai se perder.</p>

 <p>Este milagre está nos detalhes do cotidiano; é preciso viver cada minuto porque ali encontramos a saída de nossas confusões, a alegria de nossos bons momentos, a pista correta para a decisão que tomaremos.</p>

 <p>Nunca podemos deixar que cada dia pareça igual ao anterior porque todos os dias são diferentes, porque estamos em constante processo de mudança.</p>
 
</div>

<div class="a-center">
 <p>Não acredite em algo simplesmente porque ouviu. Não acredite em algo simplesmente porque todos falam a respeito.</p> 
 
 <p>Não acredite em algo simplesmente porque está escrito em seus livros religiosos. Não acredite em algo só porque seus professores e mestres dizem que é verdade.</p>

 <p>Não acredite em tradições só porque foram passadas de geração em geração. Mas depois de muita análise e observação, se você vê que algo concorda com a razão, e que conduz ao bem e beneficio de todos, aceite-o e viva-o.</p>
 
 <p>Não acredite em algo simplesmente porque ouviu. Não acredite em algo simplesmente porque todos falam a respeito.</p> 
 
 <p>Não acredite em algo simplesmente porque está escrito em seus livros religiosos. Não acredite em algo só porque seus professores e mestres dizem que é verdade.</p>

 <p>Não acredite em tradições só porque foram passadas de geração em geração. Mas depois de muita análise e observação, se você vê que algo concorda com a razão, e que conduz ao bem e beneficio de todos, aceite-o e viva-o.</p>
 
 <p>Não acredite em algo simplesmente porque ouviu. Não acredite em algo simplesmente porque todos falam a respeito.</p> 
 
 <p>Não acredite em algo simplesmente porque está escrito em seus livros religiosos. Não acredite em algo só porque seus professores e mestres dizem que é verdade.</p>

 <p>Não acredite em tradições só porque foram passadas de geração em geração. Mas depois de muita análise e observação, se você vê que algo concorda com a razão, e que conduz ao bem e beneficio de todos, aceite-o e viva-o.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para descer o texto quando chegar a resolução 600px, você tem que colocar o media screen na parte inferior, para ele ser herdado.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
```

Adicione:

```
.a-right {float: none; width: 100%}
.a-center {width: 100%}
```

Dentro da media screen, assim o texto vai descer, coloquei width:100%;, mas se quiser fazer mais configurações no texto fica a seu critério.

Veja o resultado com o seu código:

https://jsfiddle.net/wictor/abudc84k/4/

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
    }
}
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
}
/* CONFIGURAÇÃO MENU */
body {margin: 0;}
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 1.5% 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #d10000;
}
ul.topnav li {float: left;}
ul.topnav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16pt;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #3d3d3d; border: 1px solid white;}
ul.topnav li a.active {background-color: #3d3d3d; border: 1px solid white;}
ul.topnav li.right {float: right; border: 1px solid white;}
/* CONFIGURAÇÃO CONTEUDO DIREITA */
.a-right {
    padding: 2%;
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
}
.a-center {
    padding: 2%;
    width: 60%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    ul.topnav li.right, 
    ul.topnav li {float: none;}
    .a-right {float: none; width: 100%}
    .a-center {width: 100%}
    body{
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: `width: 100%` pra elementos em display:block? acha isso mesmo necessário?

Comment: Eu evitei alterar o código, tentei fazer o minimo para apresentar o resultado que ele deseja, já que é apenas um estudo, mas qual é o problema de deixar um elemento com width 100% e display block?

Comment: Wictor sabe a diferença de block, inline-block e inline? Sabe o que é "box model"? O problema esta nisto, o controle de margem, bordas, espaçamentos e até com overflow possiveis

Comment: Então não entendi direito, mas vou pesquisar melhor, mas se eu utilizar width 100% eu não devo utilizar display block em qualquer caso?

Comment: Wictor é que acho que você não entende o comportamento box-model então, dá uma pesquisada e depois leia sobre `box-sizing`, vai ajudar você a entender os possiveis problemas de efeitos colaterais.

Comment: Show de bola amigo, não sabia da existência dessa regra, obrigado!